# django-filters ModelChoiceFilter does nothing

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-filters

I am trying to add a drop down into my django filter  for thisI am using ModelChoiceFilter

below is the relevant content of my model.py

However nothing happens and the test input remains the same   ?Any idea why it is happening?

BTW any feedback on  how task of having controlled  input in filter  can be resolved in django  better then just drop down -- you are very welcome to provide your feedback. It will be not possible  for the  user to use the drop down when the amount of data will be huge.

```
 class CompanyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
        class Meta:
            model = Company
            fields = ['author','updated_by','name','country', 'state_province',
            'city','zip_code','phone',
            'zip_code','keywords']

            name = django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=Company.objects.all().order_by('name')
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class CompanyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name=django_filters.ModelChoiceFilter(queryset=Company.objects.all().order_by('name'))
    class Meta:
        model = Company
        fields = ['author','updated_by','name','country', 'state_province',
        'city','zip_code','phone',
        'zip_code','keywords']
```

read this https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/ref/filters.html#modelchoicefilter

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit how your solution works?

Comment: Why are you linking to a page that has not yet been written?